# Generate a sequence by formula with R

Tags: r

I want to generate a sequence:

```
X_n= |X_{n-1} - epsilon_n|,
```

where `epsilon_n` has an exponential distribution.

For example

```
epsilon <- rexp(100, rate = 0.3)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a sequence by formula with R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477782/generate-a-sequence-by-formula-with-r)

Comment: That thread seems to have been deleted, @joran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## n is length of the sequence, X0 is initial value, 
## default exponential rate is 0.3
xSeq <- function(n,X0,rate=0.3){
  vOut <- rep(0,n)
  vOut[1] <- X0
  eSeq <- rexp(n-1,rate)
  for(i in 2:n){
    vOut[i] <- abs(vOut[i-1]-eSeq[i-1])
    vOut
  }
  return(vOut)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Reduce`:

```
X0 <- 10
set.seed(42)
epsilon<-rexp(100, rate = 0.3)
eps <- c(X0, epsilon)

X <- Reduce(function(x, y) abs(x-y), eps, accumulate = TRUE)

plot(X)
```

[image]

Comment: It's very interesting! Thank you for the 'reduce' function!